# Can I stop desktop.ini file creation by OS in windows 7?

Tags: windows, operating-system, desktop.ini

I want to stop creation of desktop.ini file by OS whenever a new user I create in Win7.

Comment: Why do you want this?  XY problem?

Answer (score 4):

A fix that doesn't involve hiding the files:

1. Open the registry editor (Start > Run > regedit).
2. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`.
3. Modify or create a DWORD called `UseDesktopIniCache` to have a value of 0 (zero).

[Source](http://jamesisin.com/a_high-tech_blech/index.php/2010/09/nevermore-be-bothered-by-desktop-ini/)